# Sencha Touch v2 - Tab views & controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, tabs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to find the way of setting up Sencha Touch v2 and tabs with tab items serving as views, backed by containers and controllers accordingly. Has anyone managed to find out how it's done, because most examples online refer to either v1.0, v1.1 or do not use MVC pattern at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much follow Ext 4.0 MVC patterns. See this article for a good tutorial:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture

There's also a good ST2 example from SenchaCon here:
https://github.com/edspencer/SenchaConDemo